# Inputting as a Char Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to get input as a character array and manipulate it. For example this is what I have. But I just started arrays and I am confused getting confused on how I should be storing the char array.

```
   void getMessage(char message[CHARACTERS])
   {
        int i = 0;
        cout << "Enter message: ";
        for (i = 0; i < CHARACTERS; i++)
        {
            cin >> message[i];
            if (message[i] == NULL)
                break;
        }
            cout << "The message you entered was:" << endl << message[i] << endl;
   }
```

Characters is equal to the constant 100 since I do not know the size of the array, it is based off of user input. When I try to get the array to output it doesn't.

Comment: please add a tag for the language

Answer (score 2):

You're making a confusion here:

```
if (message[i] == NULL)
```

In C++, `NULL` is defined as a macro and expanded to zero, so what you're actually testing is

```
if (message[i] == 0)
```

This is hardly possible if you're inputting from a terminal or a text file (You're surely not reading a binary file in this way!). Change it to either of below depending on your needs, then it should work.

```
// Input a line
if (message[i] == '\n') {
    message[i] = '\0'; // strip the newline
    break;
}
```

```
// Input until something goes wrong
if (cin.fail()) {
    message[i] = '\0';
    break;
}
```

```
// Or combine them:
if (message[i] == '\n' || cin.fail()) {
    message[i] = '\0';
    break;
}
```

It's also a good manner to remember to terminate the string, in case you read all the buffer and `cout` would output everything before a zero character, being a potential access violation:

```
for (...) {...}
message[CHARACTERS - 1] = '\0'.
```

---

Moreover, your output statement is also wrong:

```
cout << "The message you entered was:" << endl << message[i] << endl;
```

You're only outputting **one character** by `message[i]`. If you want to output the entire message, strip the array indexing operator:

```
... << message << ....
```

so that you're using the `ostream& operator <<(const char*)` overload to output a string.

Answer (score 1):

So putting all that together, the obvious Modern C++ way to do what you want is:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::flush;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::size_t;

template <size_t CHARACTERS>
void getMessage(char(& message)[CHARACTERS]) {
  int i = 0;
  cout << "Enter message: " << flush;

  for (i = 0; i < CHARACTERS; i++) {
    if (!cin.get(message[i])
      || message[i] == '\0'
      || message[i] == '\r'
      || message[i] == '\n') {
      message[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
  cout << "The message you entered was:" << endl << message << endl;
}

int main() {
  char message[200];
  getMessage(message);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The outstanding problem being that if the buffer is filled, it won't be '\0' terminated, and then Bad Things™ happen.

Comment: Sorry, but the *Modern C++* method is to use `std::string` and not character arrays.

Comment: The OP was using character arrays.  Seemed like that was important.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int CHARACTERS = 100;

void getMessage(char message[CHARACTERS])
   {
        int i = 0;
        cout << "Enter message: ";
        for (i = 0; i < CHARACTERS-1; i++)
        {
            message[i] = cin.get(); // cin >> message[i] can't detect enter press as was in your case, so you need to use a lower level function like cin.get()
            if (message[i] == '\n'){
                message[i+1] = '\0'; // This is a c++ marker for end of string otherwise garbage values will print
                break;
            }
        }
            cout << "The message you entered was:" << endl << message << endl; //You were printing only one letter of the message
   }

int main()
{
    char inputArray[CHARACTERS];
    getMessage(inputArray);
}
```

Run online: http://cpp.sh/6rh3w

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but you'll want to adjust the loop condition to be i < CHARACTERS - 1. otherwise you'll access outside of the array when i = 99 and message[i] = '\n'. Alternatively just replace the '\n' with '\0'...